# Is there an error in Python 3's random.SystemRandom.randint, or am I using in incorrectly?

Tags: python, random

```
>>> import random
>>> random.SystemRandom.randint(0, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    random.SystemRandom.randint(0, 10)
TypeError: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

SystemRandom is supposed to give random numbers though `os.urandom`, `randint` works like normal `randrange`:

```
>>> print(random.SystemRandom.randint.__doc__)
Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
```

In IDLE a little popup suggestion appears when I type it it saying

```
`random.SystemRandom.randint(self, a, b)`
```

I think this is the cause. I'm not very good at using classes and understanding how they work, but the first argument seems to be being passed as `self`, when it should be `a`. I never really understand why `self` is used when it isn't even a keyword, and how it's supposed to all just work, but it generally does.

Am I doing this wrong, or should I report this to the Python Foundation whenever one is supposed to do such things?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`random.SystemRandom` is an class. It needs to be instantiated;

```
In [5]: foo = random.SystemRandom()

In [6]: foo.randint(0, 10)
Out[6]: 0
```

The complete docstring gives a hint;

```
In [12]: random.SystemRandom.randint?
Signature: random.SystemRandom.randint(self, a, b)
Docstring: Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.4/random.py
Type:      function
```

The `self` parameter indicates that this `randint` is a *method* of `SystemRandom`.

Answer (score 10):

I think you want:

```
import random
r = random.SystemRandom()
print(r.randint(0, 10))
```

instead.

This is because you need to create an instance of the `random.SystemRandom` class.

However you can just as easily use the following:

```
import random
random.randint(0, 10)
```

if you don't need an OS-dependent cryptographic RNG.

Comment: Using `SystemRandom` over module-level functions isn't about whether you want separate instances. `SystemRandom` uses an OS-dependent cryptographic RNG, whereas `random.randint` just uses a Mersenne Twister; the choice of which to use depends on the strength of the RNG you need.

Answer (score 3):

When the error is "*TypeError: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'*" it's because the person writing the code probably mixed up their

```
random.randint()
```

and their

```
random.choice()
```

Hope I helped :D

Comment: This might help people facing the error (missing required arg) however note that it is not a direct answer to the original question, as the OP wonders why random.SystemRandom.randint requires three arguments instead of the two arguments that they provided

Comment: True, I'm just saying because I messed up before with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

May be while using Jupyter notebook you got an error like this ,Just pass the missing positional argument like randint(1,1000) it will generate a random number bw 1 to 1000.Or Re-run the random module then try to execute both will work fine